# How do you create a custom themed NSButton?

Tags: cocoa

How do you create a custom themed NSButton? I don't mean in a small way like changing the background color or changing from rounded edges to square edges. I want to replace the entire look and feel of the button. Is that even possible to do in Cocoa? Obviously I would have to subclass the NSButton class and go from there. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, you need to subclass `NSButtonCell`. You should read [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/ControlCell.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000015) on this to gain a better understanding of how they interact. You probably will still want to subclass `NSButton` so that it will use your `NSButtonCell` subclass, too.

For a button, most of the work is done in `drawBezelWithFrame:inView:`. If you want to alter the way the text or image is drawn, you would override `drawTitle:withFrame:inView:` and `drawImage:withFrame:inView:`.

Comment: Yep, that's the best way to do it.
Note, if you're using Interface Builder and Mac OS 10.5 you no longer have to subclass NSButton. Simply drag/drop the button in your nib and then change the cell class to your custom class.

Comment: This is true. Any more, the only time you'd really need to subclass `NSButton` is if you were creating the controls programmatically.

Comment: Can I just want to replace the appearance by setting a property? I was able to change the appearance by using the "image" property of the button but I got an ugly gray rectangle whenever the custom button is clicked (the image has a transparency).

Thanks.

Comment: it's - (NSRect)drawTitle:(NSAttributedString *)title withFrame:(NSRect)frame inView:(NSView *)controlView; (Available in Mac OS X v10.4 and later), not drawText:...

Comment: Is this up to date with building Cocoa apps in swift (2), OSX 10.11 and xcode 7?  The linked documentation seems lackluster even at that point, and now half of the methods mentioned don't exist anymore.